# PayPal check stop subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Is there a way to stop paypal subscription via HTML form?
(E.g. there is a form on my website that is submit somewhere on paypal.com)

I do not use API, but I use notify (IPN) URL and have subscription ID I want to cancel.

Comment: thanks, I was not 100 % sure, this is why I asked. pls do it as answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal Standard Subscriptions do not have any API available to cancel profiles. You would need to be using the Recurring Payments API in order to have that ability.